# Please help me with this set operation (Corrected question)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

"$A$ and $C$ are disjoint sets, schematize $(A^c \cup B^c)\cap C$."

Please help me. My answer was "$C$".

Thank you.

(I can't comment, so I put the upgraded question...)

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 1):

Your are right.

Notice that  $C \subset A^c$, of course,  $C \subset A^c \cup B^c$ since $A$ and $C$ are disjonit.

Comment: But $A$ and $C$ are disjoints

Comment: in the counterexample $A\cap C\neq \emptyset$

Comment: O, yes, I'v edited it. Is it Okay?

Comment: @Paul $\{3\}=C$

Comment: OOOOOOO,I should  beat my head on the desk 100 times!

Comment: According to the Morgan Law: 

(A^c) U (B^c) = A^c ∩ B^c 

By associative property:

(A^c ∩ B^c)∩ C= A^c ∩ (B^c ∩ C) 


B^c ∩ C = C
A^c ∩ C = C

So, (A^c U B^c)∩ C= C

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Given $A$, $C$ are disjoint then:

$$\begin{align}(A^c\cup B^c)\cap C &= (A^c\cap C)\cup(B^c\cap C) \\ &= C\cup (B^c\cap C) \\ &= C\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Your asnwer is correct: Show that if $A\cap C=\emptyset$ then $C\subseteq A^c$